# Select surrounding a tag from img with regex

Tags: regex

Take the following code as an example

```
<a style="clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;" href="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/xxxxxxx.JPG"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" alt="" width="200" height="150" border="0" /></a>
```

How can I create a regular expression to strip out any link tag containg the domain 'blogspot.com' from the img tag?

In the end I would want this

```
<img src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" alt="" width="200" height="150" border="0" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: *Please* read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/62576

Comment: I need to do this because I've imported an entire blogspot site to wordpress and the posts have image links to blogspot.  Any alternative you could point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I suggest you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). If you still want the regex..

You can use the following to match:

```
<[^>]*?href\s*=\s*"[^>]*?blogspot\.com[^>]*>(<img[^>]*?\/>)<\/[^>]*>
```

And replace or extract with `$1`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yM1dM7/2)